# Why doesn't my SelectList like contents of my IList?

Tags: list, asp.net-core, razor-pages, selectlist

Here is the relevant code in my Razor page: I get an error message stating that the object (on the select element line) was not set to an instance of an object.

```
<select asp-for="EmployeeLocation.EmployeeID" asp-items="@Model.EmployeeSelectList">
```

Here is the relevant code in my PageModel class:

```
public EmployeeLocation EmployeeLocation { get; set; }
public Employee Employee { get; set; }

public class JoinResult
{
    public int EmployeeID;
    public string LastName;
}
private IQueryable<JoinResult> JoinResultIQueryable;
private IList<JoinResult> JoinResultIList;
public SelectList EmployeeSelectList;

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{

    // Get the employee's locations.
    List<int> EmployeeLocationsList = HttpContext.Session.GetObject<List<int>>("EmployeeLocationsList");

    // Populate the employee select list.

    JoinResultIQueryable = (
        from e in IDDSContext.Employee
        join p in IDDSContext.Position on e.PositionID equals p.PositionID
        join el in IDDSContext.EmployeeLocation on e.EmployeeID equals el.EmployeeID
        where e.Active == true
            && e.PositionID != 1 // Do not display the super administrator's data.
            && EmployeeLocationsList.Contains(el.LocationID)
        select new JoinResult
        {
            EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
            LastName = e.LastName
        });

    JoinResultIList = await JoinResultIQueryable
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(jr => jr.LastName)
        .ToListAsync();

    // Display the results in the Output window. Just done to show contents of JoinResultIList (see below).
    foreach (var item in JoinResultIList)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("[" + item.EmployeeID + "][" + item.LastName + "]");
    }

    // ***** The problem seem to occur here. Evidently, the SelectList doesn't like contents of the IList. Why is this happening?
    EmployeeSelectList = new SelectList(JoinResultIList, "EmployeeID", "LastName");

}
```

Here are the contents of JoinResultIList (in the Output window):

```
[4][Anderson (OH)]
[30][Becon (OH)]
[26][Smith (OH)]
[25][Stevens (OH)]
```

Comment: Hi @Bob, Base on your code, I have created a sample using your code, everything works well, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGeqE.gif). I suggest you could try to clear the browser data (cache cookie and so on), then check whether the code works well or not. Besides, you could also add a break point in this line using VS 2019: `<select asp-for="EmployeeLocation.EmployeeID" asp-items="@Model.EmployeeSelectList" ></select>`, then debug your code and check whether the EmployeeSelectList contains items or not. If still not working, perhaps the issue is related other code, check it.

Comment: Hi, @ZhiLv. I cleared the cache, and that didn't work. I also set a breakpoint where you suggested. It shows SelectedValue = null, Items = 4, DataTextField = LastName, and DataValueField = EmployeeID. The 4 items also have the correct EmployeeID and LastNames. (I had set one in the PageModel class before, which showed the same thing). I will try your code and compare to see if there is some difference there.

Comment: I compared my EmployeeSelectList (ESL) to one I call LocationSelectList (LSL), which works perfectly. The ESL requires a join between the Employee table and the EmployeeLocation table. The LSL does not require a join an thus there are no problems. After populating both select lists and hovering over them (I've set a breakpoint), I see a difference in how the data in the select lists are structured. To see the attributes of the Employee table, which I need access to, I must drill down one additional level. How do I set it up so that I have direct access to the data of both tables?

Comment: Causes error:     EmployeeSelectList = new SelectList(IDDSContext.EmployeeLocation
        .Include(e => e.Employee)
        .Where(el => EmployeeLocationsList.Contains(el.LocationID))
        .AsNoTracking()
        .OrderBy(el => el.Employee.LastName), "EmployeeID", "LastName");

Comment: Does not cause error:             LocationSelectList = new SelectList(IDDSContext.Location
                .Where(l => EmployeeLocationsList.Contains(l.LocationID))
                .AsNoTracking()
                .OrderBy(l => l.Location1), "LocationID", "Location1");

Comment: Hi @Bob, From your description, The EmployeeLocation and Employee table are configured relationship, to query the inner data (employee table), you could use Include and SelectMany() method, try to use the following code: `EmployeeSelectList = new SelectList(IDDSContext.EmployeeLocation.Include(e => e.Employee).Where(el =>EmployeeLocationsList.Contains(el.LocationID)).AsNoTracking().SelectMany(el => el.Employee.Select(e => new JoinResult() { EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID, LastName = e.LastName })).Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(el => el.Employee.LastName), "EmployeeID", "LastName");`

Comment: If it still cannot be used, can you share related class definitions (such as EmployeeLocation and Employee classes)? Then, I can create an example based on your class and try to reproduce the problem, it can help us solve the problem easier.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So, here is the solution I came up with.

```
// Get the employee's locations.
List<int> EmployeeLocationsList = HttpContext.Session.GetObject<List<int>>("EmployeeLocationsList");

// Populate the employee select list.
IQueryable JoinResultIQueryable = (
    from e in IDDSContext.Employee
    join p in IDDSContext.Position on e.PositionID equals p.PositionID
    join el in IDDSContext.EmployeeLocation on e.EmployeeID equals el.EmployeeID
    where e.Active == true
        && e.PositionID != 1 // Do not display the super administrator's data.
        && EmployeeLocationsList.Contains(el.LocationID)
    orderby e.LastName, e.FirstName
    select new
    {
        EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
        Employee = $"{e.LastName}, {e.FirstName} ({p.Position1})",
    });
EmployeeSelectList = new SelectList(JoinResultIQueryable, "EmployeeID", "Employee");
```